# PHP. Является ли строка целым числом?

Tags: php, преобразование-типов

Проблема в следующем: нужно определить, является ли строка целым числом. Перепробовал многое, но ничего не работает корректно. Вот:

```
if(is_int($value)) { ...
```

Если предавать аргумент как string, т.е. в кавычках, например, '123', то даже в этом случае возвращается false.

```
if((int)($value)) { ...
```

Если делать преобразование типа, то в этой ситуации возвращается true, если аргумент число с плавающей точкой...тоже не подходит :(

```
if(ctype_digit($value)) { ...
```

В этом же варианте возвращается true, даже если аргумент начинается с нуля, т.е. '0123', что по сути не является целым числом.

Может у кого-то есть рабочий вариант?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: «по сути не является целым числом» — почему?

Comment: @andreymal потому что для автора 0 - число типа float )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

1. Целое - 0.2s (TRUE)
2. Целое типа строка ("12") - 0.2s (TRUE)
3. Float -   0.2s (FALSE)
4. Float типа  строка ("12.25") - 0.2s (FALSE)

---

```
if ((is_int($val) || ctype_digit($val)) && (int)$val >= 0 )  echo 'true'; else echo 'false';
```

Как и в принципе, вариантов куча. Если не брезгуете быстродействием, то хоть через "регулярки" пихайте.

А, и про число 0 - это **целое число**.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score -1):

Ну, а если как-то так:

```
function isDigit($value) {
    return false !== strpos($value, '.')
        ? false
        : is_numeric($value);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать!